# AngularJS model binding breaks when deleted from

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, model

I'm building an AngularJS application to create multiple choice quizzes. The questions and related choices are added to or deleted from the following model.

```
$scope.testFormChoiceCount = [
{question: '', choices: [
    {choice: ''},
    {choice: ''},
    {choice: ''}
  ]
},
{question: '', choices: [
    {choice: ''},
    {choice: ''},
    {choice: ''}
  ]
},
];
```

**My problem case is:**
I add a question and a new object is added to the model array. Then, if I delete for example the first question, the model binding breaks resulting in the inputs of the last question throwing "b is undefined" error when I try to type into them.

Am I doing the whole ng-model binding wrong? Can anyone help me with this problem.

**The Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/D7M2Z/

**Here's how I delete and object from the model array**

```
$scope.removeQuestion = function(index){
  $scope.testFormChoiceCount.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Adding is not working when all questions are deleted.

Comment: If you delete all questions, there is no model to build on anymore. That's something I haven't prevented yet. But if you add a question and the delete a previous one, the last one breaks. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/748qR/)

In this line:

```
   for( var i=0; i<$scope.testFormChoiceCount[0].choices.length; i++ ){
      newobject.choices.push(new Object({choice : ''}));
   }
```

When you delete all objects there is no value of $scope.testFormChoiceCount[0].choices.length

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. I would have had to deal with it eventually. It however was not the question bugging me. If in the beginning you delete the first question, you can no longer write to the remaining option fields. Any thoughts on why this bind goes wrong?

Comment: This is wrong:   <input name="vastaus{{outerIndex}}-{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="testFormChoiceCount[outerIndex - 1].choices[$index].choice" /> i don't have a time but you need to think how resolve outerIndex other way, it cose more problems. If you will not resovle this I will try later.

Comment: Thanks! There really was a problem with the outerindex value. Or better said, with my use of ng-init. The choises-array receives wrong values after I've deleted an object from a lower index.